# jquery custom carousel within image zoom modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

My current code is a slider for images. When you click any image it opens up a larger version in a modal window. Its worth saying that I cannot use a plugin for this and I've looked at other Q&A on here but answers are either outdated or do not work for my situation.

At the moment you cannot slide through the larger images within the modal, you can only open/close the image you are on.  I would like to enable a slider within the modal window that will simply scroll through the larger images left to right. I've setup the next / right buttons to try and get them to simply fade in/out the next/prev images but they don't do anything currently.

Please see the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/293sh54n/3/) I have created to simulate my current setup.

**JS**

```js
 $(".product--slider .slide").each(function(index) {
   // Show the modal window
   $('#product-slider-flickity img').click(function() {
     $("#imageshow").html('<img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '"/>');
     $(".p-image-zoom").addClass("md-show");
   });
 });


 $('.md-close-zoom').click(function() {
   $('.p-image-zoom').removeClass('md-show');
 });

 $('#imageshow').click(function() {
   $(".p-image-zoom").removeClass("md-show");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product--slider" id="product-slider-flickity" data-flickity='{ "wrapAround": true, "pageDots": false, "imagesLoaded": true, "draggable": false }'>
  <div class="slide image-1">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/1024/1024" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide image-2">
    <img src="http://fillmurray.com/1024/1024" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide image-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x1024" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="md-modal p-image-zoom">
  <div class="md-content">
    <div id='imageshow'></div>
    <button class="md-close-zoom">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="md-overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Seems to work. I click the blue buttons and the kitten she slide !

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Its when you click on the image to reveal the modal. You'll see next / previous buttons that don't currently work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out what I have done mate let me know if its ok or not..https://jsfiddle.net/293sh54n/6/

```
  $('.left').click(function(){
   if(activeDivimg < 1 ){
    activeDivimg = 2
    }else{
      activeDivimg = activeDivimg - 1
    }
    console.log('left'+activeDivimg)
    $("#imageshow").html('<img src="'+$('.slide').eq(activeDivimg).find('img').attr('src')+'"/>');
        console.log(activeDivimg+"asd")
  });

  $('.right').click(function(){
  if (activeDivimg == 2){
      activeDivimg = 0
  }else{
      activeDivimg = activeDivimg + 1
  }
```

Comment: Yeah thats a great start. Thanks. Will this code work for any number of images?

Comment: I've been playing with your code but it doesn't seem to support any number of images. My scenario requires this unfortunately.